# Linux sed replacing word in generic way

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to do a sed command in Linux to uncomment the "#auth"

Original file

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
```

I can write this command to do it:

```
sed 's/#auth.*sufficient.*pam_wheel.so trust use_uid/auth\t    sufficient\t  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid/' /etc/pam.d/su
```

But I think it is too long. Is there any better way to do this (more generic)?
I don't want to specific the line number to replace it, because if someone changed the file, the script will not run normally.

**For example:**

Search keyword "**#auth.*sufficient.*pam_wheel.so trust use_uid**", if found, replace this the word "**#auth**" to "**auth**", and then append the later wording in the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed, look up the `-i` option that allows in-place modification and then anchor the regular expression. For instance:

```
 sed -i '/^#auth.*pam_wheel/s/^#//' INPUTFILE
```

will look for lines beginning with "#auth" that include "pam_wheel" later on the line and replace the "#" at the beginning with nothing.